# Remove tags (and tag content) but leave text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-manipulation

Given HTML of this form:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Generic Anchor</a>
    <li> Some text </li>
    <b> More stuff </b>
    Just text.
</div>
```

Where the tags are random, is there a way in jQuery (or Javascript) to reduce it to ONLY the text, meaning

```
<div>
    Just text.
</div>
```

Without having to specify particular tags to strip (I'm aware of .text(), but I don't want the contents of the tags I'm removing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5SRLE/1/

```
$("div").children().remove();
```

Of course, you'll want to target the specific `div` with that selector (if you have other divs that you don't want to remove children from). If you have problems, show your context so we can make it more specific... or give your div an id like `myDiv` and then use the selector `$("#myDiv")` in place of `$("div")`

Comment: That seems to work, but for some reason after doing `$(this).children().remove()`, `$(this).text()` fails, but `this.textContent` works.  Is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: `text()` seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/5SRLE/2/. If for some reason `text()` doesn't work for you but `textContent` does, go ahead and use `textContent` (or even `innerHTML` since you already removed the non-text content). If you can just use an element property rather than a jquery method, I prefer to do that anyway.

Comment: Yah, I have no idea why `text()` isn't working, but it doesn't make a difference if I can get the text anyway.